# How can I dynamically load the functions of java.lang.Math

Tags: java, math, dynamic, methods, loading

I need to dynamically load the functions of java.lang.Math and when chosenbe able to use that function.

I've tried this but it didn't work.It gives me a null pointer exception.

```
private static Class<Math> Math;

 for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor
                : Introspector.getBeanInfo(Math).getPropertyDescriptors()) {

            System.out.println(propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod());
        }
```

Comment: What gives you the NPE?

Comment: Did you "load" the Math class before doing all this ..?

Comment: Just elaborating a little bit - you need to load the class (ex: using `Class.forName()`) before introspecting it. Also, you are using wrong APIs here. Use `Introspector.getBeanInfo(mathClass).getMethodDescriptors()` - The question is closed. So take cues from this comment and try.